# Может ли пользователь узнать о существовании страницы, ссылок на которую нет

Tags: веб-программирование

### Суть вопроса

Вопрос чисто теоретический, касается структуры сайта. Каким образом посетитель сайта может узнать о существовании страницы, на которую не существует ни одной ссылки, за исключением метода тыка в адресной строке?

### Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На рисунке изображена полная структура сайта. Она состоит из:

- Главная, страница белого цвета (Путь: `/`)
- Страницы с информацией, серый цвет (Пути: `/about`, `/offers`, `/contacts`)
- Страница с информацией об истории, тёмно-серый цвет (Путь: `/history`)

Пользователь заходит на сайт и видит на шапке три ссылки, каждая из которых ведёт на разные страницы. В страницу с историей основания некой компании, выделенная тёмным цветом, нельзя попасть, так как в шапке, да и везде в общем, ничего не перенаправляет клиента туда.

### Итог

Верно ли утверждение, что перебор возможных вариантов в адресной строке для получения доступа в недоступную страницу, является единственным вариантом туда попасть? Может ли продвинутый пользователь каким-нибудь образом получить полную карту сайта?

Вопрос крайне тупой, но очень интересно теоретически знать ответ на него.

Comment: Никаким, кроме перебора

Comment: Через robots.txt. Если вы туда пропишите адреса, которые боты будет обходить стороной, хакеры в первую очередь будут изучать эти страницы.

Comment: Также в популярных движках есть всякие конструкторы sitemap.xml и прочей шушеры для более глубокого управления индексами сайта. Там тоже можно подчерпнуть. Плюс еще не маловажно смотреть что проиндексировал WebArchive и ко. Периодически они индексируют всякие debug-данные, которые могут вывести на закрытые страницы. В отличии от индекса Яндексов и гуглов, в индексы архивов хранятся куда дольше и могут быть доступны вообще навсегда...

Comment: @DiD всё же ссылки, прописанные в robots.txt и sitemap.xml, противоречат заданному в вопросе условию «не существует ни одной ссылки»

Comment: @andreymal, дык сейчас ссылок может и не существует. Но когда-то однажды до этого могла проскакивать например при разработке... тот же `var_dump()` в php не использовали никогда?

Comment: @DiD в любом случае из этого следует, что ссылки где-то продолжили своё существование

Comment: @andreymal Ну я имел в виду некоторые приемы по получению карт сайтов из osint. Кое-какие люди специально ищут именно debug-данные в индексах поисковых систем и архивах... Тот же var_dump имеет отличительный синтаксис, который легко извлекать из гигабайтов текстовых информаций на страницах сайтов. Части SQL-запросов тоже полезны...